# wakanda mobile prototyper drag&drop bug

Tags: wakanda

I'm new to Wakanda and 4D and I'm trying to make a test app, but when I try to use the prototyper for the mobile web view I can't drag&drop datasources

[Prototyper before trying to add datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEGPu.png)

When drag&dropping a datasource on that listview it should straightly generate the listview content, but with me it shows me the widget creation popup and if I click on yes it stays indefinitely on the please wait step.

[Widget creation popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nE9D.png)

I've reset everything and even reinstalled Wakanda but nothing helps.
I'm on Wakanda v1.1.4 and 4D v17.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wakanda Application Framework (WAF) is deprecated.  You're going to want to use a front-end framework like Angular or Aurelia (my preference).

Comment: Is it easily compatible with a 4D database?

Comment: Wakanda Server works with 4D.  You can use any front end.  If you only care about iOS, you might try out 4D for iOS.

Comment: Wakanda 2 offers Angular connector to replace prototyper for frontend development. Here is the link to its docs: https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/guide?section=main